# avoid addition of string and number in typescript?

Tags: javascript, typescript, types

I want to two values in typescript code say

```
let a:number = b + c;
```

And `b` and `c` come at runtime but are supposed to be number.

But if one of `b` or `c` comes as string, it will cause `a` to be string and that can cause bug down the line,  we have no way to detect that at runtime

What can I do in typescript ( if any ) to avoid this situation to happen ?

PS: I know typescript goes out of picture during runtime but just wanted to know if someone has to say something about this sort of problem.

Comment: Sooo, how is my answer going? We waste free time here for you. At least give a bit of feedback... :-(

Answer (score 4):

Well, first you should think **why `b` or `c` don't have types**.

The Typescript way to "fix" this is to force `b` and `c` to have `number` type. If you try to call `sum` with non-number arguments, it will complain AT COMPILE/LINTING TIME (not at runtime).

```
function sum(b:number, c:number) {
    let a = b + c;
}
```

This way you force both variables to be numbers, so the result `a` will also be a number.

If `b` and `c` come from another location (user input?) where you don't have control of its type, you cannot do anything with Typescript. Typescript is a type checking language that will check everything before compilation. After that, it will compile to plain Javascript.

The way to go here is to sanitize inputs (TIP: That's a good practice! :-) by, for example, checking the types at runtime, like so:

```
if (typeof b !== "number") {
    b = Number(b) || 0;
}
```

Comment: I've tried to edit the language a couple of times, but as you are still changing your answer they get rejected, so some suggestions for clarity - "types" rather than "typings" and "cannot do anything" rather than "cannot do nothing" (cannot do nothing is a double-negative meaning you CAN do something, which is not what you mean).

Comment: @EuanSmith Oh, sorry haha. Not going to do any small change anymore. Thank you for the suggestions. I always fall in the double negative as is really common in my main language.. :-/ Edit it again so you get the edit reward xD

Comment: No worries.  It always impresses me that anybody can answer coherently in a language other than their own!

Answer (score 2):

You can use the parseInt or parseFloat functions, or simply use the unary + operator:

```js
let b = "3";
let c = 2;
let a = ((+b)+(+c));  // a: number

console.log(a)
```

Answer (score 2):

use let c = parseInt(b)+parseInt(c)

Comment: `parseInt("2"+"3")` will return `23` which is probably not what you want

Comment: @MauriceNino please don't edit an answer in a way that completely changes it, even if you're correct. Make your own answer instead.